# How to close full screen ads without clicking on close button?

Tags: android

I want to close full screen interstitial ads after some period of time like 10 seconds. How it can be possible through code?

Comment: As per i know, you can not do this. Because there are not any methods available to hide or close ads programetically. User must need to press back or close ads. But you can achieve this by programetically fire hardware back button event.

Answer (score 2):

You can fire the `back button` event automatically after some delay like this

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
   }
}, 10000); // 10seconds delay
```